# How to format numbers in mysql to output in shortened form?

Tags: mysql

How do i format numbers in a Mysql table field so that they are formatted properly e.g. 150,000 shows as 150k,  2,500,000 shows as 2.5M etc

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific data type or format for this,All you can do is just make the respective column  a "char" field and than you can store numbers in this format.